# 80s horror movie with a female demon who transforms into a blonde in a black outfit?

Tags: story-identification, movie

This movie must have been an Empire/Full Moon feature but I remember seeing a scene from it on DeviantArt in which a deadite-esque demon turns into a blonde model in a black outfit, I definitely think it was a bikini or swimsuit, I don’t remember the movie’s title but it was on YouTube.  It was a silver swimsuit.

Comment: Black or silver?

Comment: I definitely recall it was a silver swimsuit, I think the actress in the deadite looking demon makeup looked like Linnea Quigley or Brinke Stevens but I do not think it was either of them, it's not Katey from Chud II: Bud the Chud's actress.

Comment: I should mention I did see the screencapture for this movie in a deviantart gallery that isn't on the site anyway...yeah, the user (Juliegrey2001) deactivated their account.